# Server Error: Unknown block type "code", please specify a serializer for it in the `serializers.types` prop

Tags: next.js, blogs, sanity

I am building a blog website using Sanity and NextJS. and facing error like:

## Server Error

*Error: Unknown block type "code", please specify a serializer for it in the `serializers.types` prop*

**I've created this object in the sanity schema.**

```
{
name: 'code',
title: 'Code Block',
type: 'code',
},
```

**frontend code:**

```
<PortableText
// Pass in block content straight from Sanity.io
content={blog.content}
projectId="########"
dataset="production"
// Optionally override marks, decorators, blocks, etc. in a flat
// structure without doing any gymnastics
serializers={{
h1: (props) => <h1 style={{ color: "red" }} {...props} />,
li: ({ children }) => (
<li className="special-list-item">{children}</li>
),
code: (props) => (
<pre>
<code {...props} />
</pre>
),
}}
/>
```

it is showing the error
[sanity code-input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jTJ6.png)